# Unable to test Jax-rs with JSON entity

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to test a Jax-rs resource by following this https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html,
and I am using container `jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http`

I can assert status code.  However, when I try to readEntity, I get exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class java.lang.String
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:248)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:181)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:217)
```

My Resource Class:

```
@Path("/")
public class SampleResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/health")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getServiceStatus() {
        return "{\"Status\": \"OK\"}";
    }    
}
```

My Test Class:

```
public class TestSampleResource extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(SampleResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHealthEndpoint() {            
        Response healthResponse = target("health").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

        Assert.assertEquals(200, healthResponse.getstatus());  // works

        String body = healthResponse.readEntity(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"Status\": \"OK\"}", body);
    }        
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 7):

The problem comes from having both Jersey and RestEasy client on the classpath. When you call `target()` on the `JerseyTest`, the `WebTarget` is obtained from a `Client` that is built by calling `ClientBuilder.newClient()`.

The [`ClientBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.java#ClientBuilder) is a standard JAX-RS API, and it is implemented first to search for an implementation of `ClientBuilder` through the `META-INF/services` files, looking for a file named `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`, whose content is the name of an implementation of the `ClientBuilder`. If no such file is found, it defaults to looking for `JerseyClientBuilder`.

`jersey-client` has no such file `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.core.ClientBuilder` because it's `ClientBuilder` is the default for JAX-RS client. If you look in your `resteasy-client` jar, you will see the it does have that file. And if you look in the contents of that file, you will see the `ResteasyClientBuilder` as the implementation.

So even though you are using Jersey's test framework, the `Client` being used, is RESTeasy's implementation. And I guess all the standard configurations with entity providers never gets configured. Conversion between String and application/json is one of those standard providers you need in your case.

I would say just explicitly use Jersey client implementation. You will no longer be able to call `target` on the `JerseyTest`. You will need to explicitly create the client

```
@Test
public void dotest() {
    final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder().build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998");
    final Response response = target.path("health").request().get();
    final String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
}
```

The default base path for `JerseyTest` is `http://localhost:9998`, so I explicitly create the `WebTarget` with that.

Note that I said the `String` to/from `application/json` is supported by standard providers. So if you will only be serializing Strings, then you don't need anything else. If you want POJO serialization support for the Jersey client (and server side), you should add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says you are missing a MessageBodyReader for content-type `application/json`. Do you have JacksonJsonProvider on your classpath? It can be added as a dependency to `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the JacksonJsonProvider in your test application:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(SampleResource.class, JacksonJsonProvider.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the json parser in your test is being misguided by the presence of curly braces. Basically it thinks you are returning a json object, not a json string.  Try returning `"Status:OK"`